# "porcentagem cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, método

Preciso definir o valor da variável `porcentagem` de acordo com o que for definido no `Spinner`. O problema é que eu preciso utilizar o valor da `porcentagem` fora do método `setOnItemSelectedListener()`, na linha `int r = edtVaoNum * porcentagem / 100;`, mas dessa forma o Eclipse aponta erro.

Segue o código:

```
    EditText edtVao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vao);
    final int edtVaoNum = Integer.parseInt(edtVao.getText().toString());

    // Spinner
    Spinner spnCargas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_cargas);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spnAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.str_cargas, R.layout.spinner_style);
    spnAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_style);
    spnCargas.setAdapter(spnAdapter);
    // Spinner

    spnCargas.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spnAdpView, View v, int carga, long id) {

                    int porcentagem;

                    if(spnAdpView.getItemAtPosition(carga).toString() == "Cargas pequenas"){ porcentagem = 4; }
                    else if(spnAdpView.getItemAtPosition(carga).toString() == "Cargas médias"){ porcentagem = 5; }
                    else { porcentagem = 6;}

                }// fecha onItemSelected

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}
            }//fecha OnItemSelectedListener
    ); // fecha setOnItemSelectedListener

    int r = edtVaoNum * porcentagem / 100;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está declarando a variável dentro do escopo do método, ou seja, ela só é válida dentro de onde você declarou ela, no caso você declarou ela dentro do método setOnItemSelectedListener() então ela só ficará visível dentro dos delimitadores {} do método, ou seja, do seu escopo. Então a solução é declarar a variável fora do método, assim:

```
EditText edtVao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vao);
final int edtVaoNum = Integer.parseInt(edtVao.getText().toString());
int porcentagem; //DECLARE AQUI

// Spinner
...
```

Comment: Consegui, mas declarando a variável antes do método onCreate. Obrigado!

Comment: Mas deu pra entender a parada do escopo né? No caso se você declarasse dentro do onCreate, ele ia ficar visível em qualquer lugar dentro do onCreate, em todos os métodos dentro dele etc. Se você declarou em um método ainda superior ao onCreate (não lembro como é a estrutra do android) que deve ser um método Main, a variável fica disponível no onCreate, no onPause, onResume etc. Abraços. Precisando estamos ai =D

Comment: Entendi sim, abraços mano! :D